# Unable to login to Azure V12 Database from MVC EF6 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have an MVC, EF6 app using SQL Azure. I just upgraded my server on Azure to V12. I'm able to run my app successfully locally using connection strings that point to my SQL Azure database. Howerver, if I attempt to run my app from the Azure web host, I'm not able to. I get an error saying 'Unable to login for user Tour'. The name of my database is Tour, but I don't have a user account named tour. The only user I have is one named WAND.

Again, my apps connects to SQL Azure fine if I run it locally. But not if I access it from my Azure webhost.

I've also executed the following, which I read I had to do with V12:  `exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Allow Windows Azure','0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0';`

I don't know why it's trying to connect via a user named Tour (the name of my database).

My connection strings look as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=---;Initial Catalog=Tour;User Id=WAND@ServerName;Password=---;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="TourEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Tour.csdl|res://*/Tour.ssdl|res://*/Tour.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=----; initial catalog=Tour; User Id=WAND@ServerName;Password=---;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database now?

Comment: Yes. As it turned out, when I published my app to Azure, a remote connection was created for me, and selected to be used. That connection string was trying to connect via a user named 'Tour'. I could have accidently selected this option, but I don't recall doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this seems as if you have connection string set on Azure itself which modifies your connection string in web.config after deployment.

You didn't state if you are using App Service - Web App or just VM, but I will assume the former.

Go to old portal, select your web app, go to Configure tab and check if you have any entries under "Connection strings" section. I've attached the sample image on how this section looks like if you aren't familiar with it.

[image: Configuration sample]

Comment: Thanks Admir. My connection strings section is empty. I think what I'm going to have to do is to delete the entire database and start over, with a new server. This happend after I renamed a database and then upgraded to V12. Seems something got fouled up.